# D3 time series heatmap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, graph-visualization

I am trying to make a heatmap using d3 which on x axis a time series, on y a number and the color is the value for the cell. The data is loaded based on the input and the domain and range can change on different input. I was not able to find such example. Does anyone have an idea how I can create that?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to get started somewhere first. Usually people here won't solve your whole job from scratch. You could, e.g., start with a [bar chart](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html) and then think how to impove it. Maybe the [stacked normalized](http://bl.ocks.org/3886394) example is somewhat similar to your idea? At least it shows you how to draw a data series using boxes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I finally got the time to write this piece of code that I was looking for. My main problem was that I had understood the scales well. So after reading a bit I could define a time scale and map it to my data with the following code:

```
var xscale = d3.time.scale()
                     .domain([startDate, endDate])
                     .range([padding, w - padding]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xscale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .ticks(d3.time.days, 5);
```

You can find a working demo of my code in the following jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TD5Sk/1/

Answer (score 4):

Explore around the [d3 gallery of examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), mixing and matching you should be able to find a good starting point.  The [co-occurrence matrix](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/) has many of the properties you describe. Even the [calendar example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/calendar.html) probably has some useful pointers.